# How to pass xml text as argument in exec ant task?

Tags: xml, ant, escaping

We need to call an executable from ant that takes xml as part of the argument. Using exec is easy enough, but one of the arguments includes an xml file. We tried loading the xml file using the loadfile target with striplinebreaks

```
<loadfile property="xmlStuff" srcFile="xmlFile.xml">
   <filterchain>
     <striplinebreaks/>
   </filterchain>
</loadfile>
<exec executable="theCommand">
   <arg value="Some other information and now our xml: '${xmlStuff}'" />
</exec>
```

Is there a way we can read and escape xml documents for use in this case?

EDIT since xmlStuff has quotes for its attributes they are ending the arg valute attribute quotes.

So the above example ends up like:

```
theCommand "Some other information and now our xml: '<outerTag myAtt="foobar"> <innerTag /> </outerTag>'"
```

Instead of:

```
theCommand Some other information and now our xml: '<outerTag myAtt="foobar"> <innerTag /> </outerTag>'
```

**Is there any way to have essentially three layers of quotes?**

One for the value attribute of the arg tag (could these perhaps not be included in the final command?).

One for within the arg tag to represent the nested string.

One for within the xmlStuff for attributes within.

This file is being injected into a database and is not available now.

Comment: What do you mean by "breaking out of the arg tag"? What is the exact error message you are getting? Works fine for me after fixing the colon after executable and trying with an executable which just echoes its arguments.

Comment: Thanks about the colon. 
I've updated the question a bit, but after evaluating ${xmlStuff} the arg tag will look like:
<arg value="Some other information and now our xml: <foo><bar /></foo>" />
The embedded xml is the big problem.

Comment: Are you sure that the variable expanding to a value containing angle brackets is actually your problem? As I understand it, Ant expands the variable references after parsing the XML, so it cannot affect parsing. I tried with your example and it does work for me. How exactly did you test, and what error did you get?

Comment: Your right, the test case seems to be working. I created it by using the same format as in production. I'll try to test in production again and post the error as well as what differs between my example and production.

Comment: Ok, so the problem seems to actually be that the quotes aren't escaping as expected. I'll update the question appropriatly. The error message in production is from the command saying that there are too many arguments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Double quotes in the value of the `value` attribute of the `arg` tag seem to cause problems on Windows (but not on Linux; tested with Ant 1.7.1).

If breaking on other platforms is not a concern, I guess a crude workaround could be just escaping the quotes which end up on the command line. You could do this for example by adding the following filter to your `filterchain`:

```
<tokenfilter>
  <replacestring from='"' to='\"'/>
</tokenfilter>
```

---

**Edit:** In your own [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1528490/how-to-pass-xml-text-as-argument-in-exec-ant-task/1723390#1723390) you reveal that "theCommand" is actually `psql`. Since it can read the query from a file using the `-f` switch, using a temporary file is really the easiest way to avoid command line troubles.

```
<tempfile property="temp.file" deleteonexit="true" />
<echo file="${temp.file}"
      message="Some other information and now our xml: '${xmlStuff}'" />
<exec executable="psql">
  <arg value="-f" />
  <arg file="${temp.file}" />
</exec>
<delete file="${temp.file}" />
```

Nevertheless, if you are inserting the XML file contents into a SQL string literal, you  should consider at least escaping apostrophes.

Comment: would there be any way to force ant not to use quotes around the arg in the final command? I've found that's the real clincher because I can't change "theCommand"

Comment: Using the `line` attribute instead of `value` allows you to specify a space-delimited list of command-line arguments: `<arg line="foo bar baz"/>` This way it won't add the quotes in there, but you get the value split into different arguments by whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the XML in a CDATA section:

```
<loadfile
  property="xmlStuff"
  srcFile="xmlFile.xml">
<![CDATA[
  <filterchain>
    <striplinebreaks/>
  </filterchain>
]]>
</loadfile>
```

Comment: I don't think you understand, I want to striplinebreaks. The problem is the contents of the file. I tried putting CDATA around the text in arg's value attribute, but this isn't allowed in ANT.

Comment: Can't you include the XML in a CDATA section as the text value of the arg tag -- i.e. <arg>cdata section with xml</arg> ?

Comment: Arg doesn't support nested text.
Error:
class org.apache.tools.ant.types.Commandline$Argument
doesn't support nested text data

Answer (score 0):

A workaround that we have been using in the meantime has been to use a file based argument instead of a command line argument for "theCommand" (actually postgresql's psql command) and manually adding the "Some other info..."(actually an insert query) to a copy of the xml file. Very messy and hard to maintain, but I thought I would post it.